# Can't find text in Language Overrides

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to find where I can update the Email Notification if the Administrator sets up a User Account but I can not find this anywhere.

I have tried looking in Extensions > Language(s) and Overrides and entering in the text I want to change but there are no results.

Does anyone know where I can update the following message:

=================================================

Subject: New User Details

Hello XXXXXXX,

You have been added as a User to Locals Supporting Locals (LSL) by an Administrator.

This email contains your username and password to log in to http://www.lsl.global/

Username: XXXXXXX
Password: XXXXXXX

Please do not respond to this message as it is automatically generated and is for information purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at StackExchange. You will have a better chance to get an answer if you ask your question there. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

The string is coming from the following file -

```
root\administrator\language\en-GB\en-GB.plg_user_joomla.ini
```

You can edit the file and make your own email template.

For more information -

> https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! :-)

Comment: Thank you for the file location, it is exactly what I was looking for. Can you tell me how you found it?

Comment: experience, I have changed email templates many times. Also I use sublime text so I just did `Ctrl+Shift+F` and searched for the string in my project :)